# Does a UK citizen need a transit visa to change planes in India?

Tags: india, international-travel, paperwork, transit-visas, uk-citizens

I am a UK citizen, flying on Jet Airways from LHR to Sri Lanka and back. I have a 2-hour stopover each way in Mumbai. My luggage is checked all the way through and I will not be leaving the airport terminal. Do I need a transit visa?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours

So no, you do **not** need a visa.

Comment: Is this generally true for India, or can this answer be expanded to make it general (e.g. what about Pakistanis)? I don't believe we have a canonical transit visa answer for India yet.

Comment: @choster True for anyone but refugees and stateless people, provided remaining airside (in practice, check-in staff, at least in Europe, will usually require the trip to be in a single booking, partially but not only due to the baggage issue)